# Why does this reverse the string?

Tags: python

```
def reverse(s):
  str = ""
  for i in s:
    str = i + str
  return str
```

I don't understand how using str in this case reverses the string?

Comment: because you're prepending each character one by one?

Comment: You iterate the characters in order and keep putting them on the start of the string. Suppose you tried "abcd". At first you'd have "a", but then "b" + "a", then "c" + "ba", etc... giving you the reverse. If you did `str = str + i` it wouldn't reverse.

Comment: FYI a script shouldn't call a variable `str` because that's a built-in name; shadowing a name renders it inaccessible.

Answer (score 2):

That's terrible naming btw. (And it's replacing the reserved keyword `str`).

I believe this should make it more readable. Explanations are given in the comments.

```
def reverse(string):
    reversed_string = ""
    for letter in string:
        reversed_string = letter + reversed_string
    
    return reversed_string
```

Comment: Its not necessarily a string, its anything iterable and addable. So a simple name of "reverse" may be okay.

Comment: Right. I just wanted to well differentiate it from `reversed` (teacher sensibilities ;)

Comment: `reversed` is also not a good name because it is also a built-in.

Comment: Right! Argh it can never be clean

Comment: How would you name `string` and `reversed_string`, without going too high in abstraction?

Answer (score 0):

Its because you prepend the characters in order. On each iteration, the i'th character becomes the first character of the result, shifting those already added to the right. In python we often use print to see what is going on. A quick change to the script shows the steps

```
def reverse(s):
    str = ""
    for i in s:
        print(repr(i), "+", repr(str), end="")
        str = i + str
        print(" ==>", repr(str))
    return str

print(reverse("abcd"))
```

Result

```
'a' + '' ==> 'a'
'b' + 'a' ==> 'ba'
'c' + 'ba' ==> 'cba'
'd' + 'cba' ==> 'dcba'
dcba
```

Comment: this helped me understand - ty